# Variable selection/potential transformation of variables

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, interaction

I am trying to complete a multiple linear regression to best explain my response variable using 3 independent variables x1, x2 and x3.

I have used ggplot() to create 3 scatter plots for x1, x2 and x3 in conjunction with y:

[image]

[image]

[image]

And when I use the lm function in R to account for interactions:

[image: ![enter image description here]

My instinct is to discard x3 due to there appearing to be no relationship in the scatter plot and insignificant p-value. Then, keep x1, x2 and include an interaction term for x1*x2.

Does this sound like a reasonable approach?

So, my current model is y = β0 + β1.x1 + β2.x2 + β3.x1.x2 + error with an adjusted r-squared of 0.4725.

Which produces this qq plot and this residuals plot:

[image]

[image]

The qq plot doesn't look very good.

Would you suggest any improvements/mistakes?

With y^(14/99) = β0 + β1.x1 + β2.x2 + β3.x1.x2 + error
[image]
[image]

Comment: Quick observations: the distribution of the response looks positively skewed in all cases. It could be residual error from unadjusted effects, or it could be begging for a change of variable. Fractional polynomials are a useful tool for finding the optimal expression of an $X$ variable as a function of the response.

Comment: The *first* thing to do is to transform $y.$  A Box-Cox transformation is attractive in this case.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/35717/919 for methodology with a worked example and https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/429367/919 for a general approach.

Comment: Thank you for bringing Box-Cox to my attention; I did not even know it existed. The lambda value came out as 0.141414... and improved the R squared from 0.47 to 0.6 and the diagnostic plots look a lot better.

Comment: $R^2$ of what? There are [issues](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/279479/247274) with comparing the $R^2$ of a model with a transformed $y$ and an untransformed $y$.

Comment: The R^2 of y = β0 + β1.x1 + β2.x2 + β3.x1.x2 + error versus y^(14/99) = β0 + β1.x1 + β2.x2 + β3.x1.x2 + error. If I've understood how the box-cox works that is. The qq-plot and residual plots in general have also improved. Would you say it is not as simple as this or this definitely an improvement?

Comment: A Box-Cox parameter of 0.14 is difficult to interpret.  Usually one would conclude this is an approximate estimate of 0, corresponding to the logarithm.  Once you have settled on this, you should throw away all your original graphics and recreate them using $\log(y)$ to see what else might be going on.  There is a hint that the conditional response of $y$ might be bimodal, suggesting a lurking binary variable.

Comment: Turns out the Box-Cox parameter was actually 0.22 but the confidence interval does not contain 0 so I'm unsure as to whether you can approximate it as 0. However, using log(y) actually produces a slightly higher adjusted R squared (which I know can be misleading) than y^0.22. Log(y) also continues to suggest the interaction is significant which is more convenient for me since I can just leave it in. But then the qq plot is better with y^0.22. We're talking small differences here so it might not be that deep anyway. Thank you for the help, it is appreciated.